# Siteminder SAML 2.0 SP to IDP partnership

Tags: saml, siteminder

We are using Siteminder 12.52. Our company is acting as Service provider and we have a Remote IDP. There is already one existing partnership with that remote idp. Now when i try to create new partnership with same remote IDP but different SP ID, i'm getting error as "Can not create Partnership with Multiple times the same Remote IDP ID".  My client said he cannot create one more entity ID and asking me to use the same entity id. Anybody faced this issue and any resolutions to it?

- JK

Answer (score 0):

As long as the partnership name was different, you should be able to associate many SP's with the same remote IDP.